How to open an e-mail in edit mode (Microsoft Graph API)
The Situation:
We use the Microsoft Graph API to create a draft message for a user. This works without any problems and in the corresponding response we get the webLink with which we can access/open the created draft message in a WebView2 window, for example.
The Problem:
The provided link opens the draft mail in the "edit mode". The user first has to click on the pencil button to edit and then send the e-mail (See screenshot below).

After opening the Link, the user has to press the pencil button to edit the email:



After clicking on the pencil button the user can finally send the e-mail:


The Question:
Is it possible to open the draft e-mail in the edit mode directly and, if yes, how?
Sadly I didn't find anything regarding this topic in the Microsoft Graph API documentation and also googling the problem was to no avail.
Our current solution is to "search" for the edit button via JavaScript and "click" on it for the user. But, as you can imagine, this is not a stable solution and we would prefer a "Microsoft approved way" of doing it.

You can change the called URL in Webview2.
If you want to change the web link directly, I don't know of a way yet. Unfortunately you cannot adjust the viewmodel=ReadMessageItem parameter to e.g. ComposeMessageItem.
